# why 12c with extended varchar2 limit still converting sql server varchar(max) to long

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle12c

Oracle version 12.1.0.2
max_string_size=extended

I am using sql server ODBC to connect to sql server database via Oracle gateway to sql server, the connection is working fine and i am able to access sql server tables.

However, as per Oracle documentation starting 12c and with extended limit on varchar2 data type the conversion of sqlserver varchar(max) to oracle Long will only happen if the length of sql server data is more than 32k.

My sql server table has few columns defined as varchar(max) in and all of those i see getting converted to LONG when i try to describe the table over dblink. 
I need to load the data from sql server to oracle and the above problem is making it very difficult as more than one long columns can not be copied over dblink.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: I think that is ok, size of `varchar2(max)` in MSSQL is up to 2G and Oracle equivalent is `long`.

Comment: You solved that problem? Because I have the same problem in oracle 19c, and in oracle11g it worked OK!

Answer (score 0):

I created a view on the SQL server side that uses substr(column,1,4000) to fit within the old Oracle max 4000 character length. This worked quite well with Oracle 11.

I am in the process of migrating to a new Oracle 18 instance that uses character set AL32UTF8 instead of WE8MSWIN1252. The exact same SQL is now getting:

> ```
> ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message:
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Program type out of range {HY003}
> ORA-02063: preceding 2 lines from CEAV195
> ```

Fortunately I don't have a tight deadline for working this out.

Comment: I am now getting

> [Error] Execution (8: 17): ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype

despite using the following in the view on the SQL Server side:

> cast(substring(cr.response,1,2000) as varchar(2000)) response

As I said earlier, this worked perfectly fine with Oracle 11 and the WE8MSWIN1252 character set.

Comment: i can not change anything on sql server side i.e. creating views etc. So i am still stuck.

Comment: You solved that problem? Because I have the same problem in oracle 19c, and in oracle11g it worked OK!

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issue and found this solution elsewhere

```
set serverout on
DECLARE
  l_cursor    BINARY_INTEGER;
  l_id VARCHAR2(60);
  l_temp      VARCHAR2(250);
  l_notes     VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  l_cursor := DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.open_cursor@remotedb;
  DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.parse@remotedb(
  l_cursor,
  'select "RecId","Notes" from "MySqlServerTable"'
);

LOOP
  DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.get_value@remotedb(l_cursor, 1, l_id);
  DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.get_value@remotedb(l_cursor, 2, l_notes);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(l_id || ' ' || l_notes);
END LOOP;

exception
  when others then
  DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.close_cursor@remotedb(l_cursor);
  raise;
END;
/
```